# React Jest: How do I mock an async API call that returns data?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, async-await, jestjs

I am trying to test a React table component (that uses an async API call to return table data), but cannot work out how to mock the API call to satisfy my React test file. I have a mock data file to supply mock data. (I have only included relevant code).

**mockData:**

```
const mockRequestData = [
    {
        "email": "runner1@test.com",
        "firstName": "runner1",
        "lastName": "runner1"
    },
    {
        "email": "runner2@test.com",
        "firstName": "runner2",
        "lastName": "runner2"
    },
    {
        "email": "runner3@test.com",
        "firstName": "runner3",
        "lastName": "runner3"
    },
];

export const mockData = {
    mockData: mockRequestData,
};
```

**apiCall is in its own file:**

```
const getAllAthletesSigningUp = async () => {
    let athletesSigningUp= [];

    const response = await returnGetResponse("/api/atheletesignup");
    if (response.status === 200) {
        return athletesSigningUp= (response.body);
    }
    return athletesSigningUp
};

export {getAllAthletesSigningUp};
```

**runnerTable app:**

```
 const [requests, setRequests] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        apiResponse();
    },[]);

    const apiResponse = async () => {
        return setRequests(await getAllAthletesSigningUp ())
    }


<div className={"table_content"}>
                {
                  requests.map((request, index) => {
                       return (
                          <>
                              <div key={index} className={"table_row"} data-testid={"tableRow"}>
                                  <p>{formatText(request.email)}</p>
                                  <p>{formatText(request.firstName)}</p>
                                  <p>{formatText(request.lastName)}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

```js
jest.mock(<path to getAllAthletesSigningUp>, () => ({
  getAllAthletesSigningUp: jest.fn(() => [<mock data>])
}))

describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    // const {getAllAthletesSigningUp} = jest.requireMock(<path>) - if You need mocked implementation in test;
    // const {getAllAthletesSigningUp} = jest.requireActual(<path>) - if You need original implementation in test;
  })
})
```

or describe implementation directly in single test with [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) or [`mockImplementationOnce()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn):

```js
jest.mock(<path to getAllAthletesSigningUp>, () => ({
  getAllAthletesSigningUp: jest.fn()
}))

describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    const {getAllAthletesSigningUp} = jest.requireMock(<path>)
    // getAllAthletesSigningUp.mockImplementation(() => [<mock data>]) - for all function calls;
    // getAllAthletesSigningUp.mockImplementationOnce(() => [<mock data>]) - for single function call;
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried your second option but I get this error: 
Property 'mockImplementationOnce' does not exist on type '() => Promise<any>'.